# Chromium background suddenly black - fonts low contrast and unreadable

Tags: themes, fonts, chromium, colors

Turned off my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS box with Chromium Version 92.0.4515.107 and went on vacation.  When I return, the Chromium background is very dark grey, and many fonts are difficult to read as they are low contrast or the same color as the background.  Many elements don't show up unless you hover the mouse over them and they get highlighted.  Google prompt on a new Chromium tab is black,used to be white with black text, recently visited page icons on a new Chromium tab have black backgrounds behind the icons and low contrast unreadable text underneath.  None of this is a result of anything I did, as the computer was off for a week. I got no time for messing around with appearance and usually jsut leave backgrounds and themes at default.

Here is what I have tried:
Change background color by clicking on the "pencil" icon in the lower right hand corner of a new tab to Solid Colors:White.  The result is a light grey,not white, same color as many fonts, can't read many items on most pages.  Fonts don't show up unless I hover over the active element.  Same menu, change "Color and Theme" to "CLassic", this changes the tabs and top bar only not the page background.

Reload several themes using settings:appearance:themes such as classic.  These change the colors of the top bar and tabs, not the background and body of the page.

Software update wanted to update Chromium so I let it.  No difference.

Settings:Advanced:Reset Settings.  Big hassle reloading a couple of extensions and default web pages I use but no change in the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:

In the address bar, type Chrome://flags/

Force Dark Mode for Web Contents has somehow been turned on without my permission.  Disable this flag, all is back to normal.

More info [here:](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/fixed-google-chrome-wrong-color-after-update/)